# Regex for validating only numbers and dots

Tags: java, regex

I want a java regex expression that accepts only the numbers and dots.

for example,

```
             1.1.1 ----valid
             1.1   ----valid
             1.1.1.1---valid
             1.    ----not valid
```

The dots should not be at the starting position or at the ending position.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

Explanation: It accepts numbers separated by dots; it starts and ends with number; a number can have multiple digits; one number without dots is also accepted.

Variant without multiple digits:

```
^\d(\.\d)*$
```

Variants where at least one dot is required:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)+$
^\d(\.\d)+$
```

Don't forget that in Java you have to escape the \ symbols, so the code will look like this:

```
Pattern NUMBERS_WITH_DOTS = Pattern.compile("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)*$");
```

Comment: This was useful to me, I needed to take the index of a summary, so I modified to it: ^(\d+[\.\d+]*). Thanks!

Comment: for a user input, I need to accept a string before they type the number after the dot, so I need to accept something like `1.` before the digit after the `.`.  Can anyone help?

Comment: @conor909 assuming you also want to accept an empty string then ^(\d+\.)*\d*$

Answer (score 5):

So you want a regex that wants numbers and periods but starts and ends with a number?

```
"[0-9][0-9.]*[0-9]"
```

But this isn't going to match things like `1`. which doesn't have any periods, but does start and end with a number.

Comment: This is working as per your condition.
Here (\.\d+)+ is checking atleast one dot with a number.   ^\d+(\.\d+)+$

\d+                                                (   \.           \d+                            )          +
Atleast one number at starting         one dot   atleast one number          atleast one

Comment: I tried to use this in android but it is still allowing dot at the start

Answer (score 2):

**I guess this is what you want:**

```
Pattern.compile("(([0-9](\\.[0-9]*))?){1,13}(\\.[0-9]*)?(\\.[0-9]*)?(\\.[0-9]*)?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Explanation: It accepts numbers separated by dots; it starts and ends with number; a number can have multiple digits; one number without dots is not accepted.

The output like this--

- 1.1
- 1.12
- 1.1.5
- 1.15.1.4

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>RegEx to allow digits and dot</p>
Number: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"^\\d(\\.\\d)*$"

1     ----valid (if it must be not valid, replace `*` => `+` )
1.1.1 ----valid
1.1   ----valid
1.1.1.1---valid
1.    ----not valid
11.1.1 ---not valid (if it must be valid, add `+` after each `d`)
```