# Remove invalid numeric chars from string

Tags: android, regex, char, hashset

I am comparing version strings by **removing all non numeric characters** and **keeping the dot "."**

```
oldStr = "Old string v1.9.552.6"
String resultOld = oldStr.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
resultOld = 1.9.552.6

newStr = "New string v2.0.1"
String resultNew = newStr.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
resultNew = 2.0.1
```

EDIT: some example strings:

```
3C New 2017 program v1.2.3253.2.5beta52 --> should be 1.2.3253.2.552
3C New 2017 program v1.2.3253.2.5 b458 --> should be 1.2.3253.2.5458
```

My problem is that sometimes a string contains **invalid numeric chars**, which makes the comparison not valid.

```
newStr = "3New 2017-string v2.0.1"
```

This would result in the following invalid version string: 320172.0.1,
so my question is how do I **remove the invalid numeric chars (3 and 2017)** from the string so I get a **valid** version string I can compare?

*PS: I do not know the invalid numeric strings upfront, so they could be any numbers.*

I already tried with comparing the chars but I think I am on the wrong track:

```
private void removeDuplicates(String oldStr, String newStr) {

        char[] charsNew = newStr.toCharArray();
        char[] charsOld = oldStr.toCharArray();
        Set<Character> NewPresent = new HashSet<>();

        for (int b = 0; b < charsOld.length; b++) {

            if (!Arrays.equals(charsNew, charsOld)) {

                NewPresent.add(charsNew[b]);
                // Just to check output
                Log.w("CHARS", NewPresent.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do your version code has any specific format

Comment: Like it will contain v and than version code ? so you could search for v and than a numeric integer

Comment: Not gonna work, sometimes the string does not contain a "v", so splitting will not work unfortuntaly. That is why I am removing all the non numeric characters.

Comment: You can search for last space and take that word and remove the non numeric characters from last word

Comment: Good thinking but what if I have a string like: 3New 2017-stringv2.0.1, this possibility is there.

Comment: But You should follow some specific rule while creating this string or else it will be difficult

Comment: I know, that makes it so hard, as some strings do not follow these rules, removing all non numeric characters and keeping the dot is the best but I am stuck on given problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161899/discussion-between-abdevelopers-and-simon).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001037/regex-for-validating-only-numbers-and-dots

Comment: Unfortunatly does not work.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
/([\d]+\..*?[^a-zA-Z]*)/g
```

here is the regex 101 demo
https://regex101.com/r/GCs7mb/3

- 1st Capturing Group ([\d]+..*?[^a-zA-Z]*) Match a single character
  present in the list below [\d]+

  - Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) \d matches a digit (equal
    to [0-9]) . matches the character . literally (case sensitive) .*?
    matches any character (except for line terminators)
    *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) Match a single
    character not present in the list below [^a-zA-Z]*
  - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) a-z a single
    character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case
    sensitive) A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65)
    and Z (index 90) (case sensitive) Global pattern flags g modifier:
    global. All matches (don't return after first match)

Comment: Thx JBone but a string could also not contain a "v" character. ABDevelopers brought me on a track using regex but this regex (\d(\.\d*)*)+\s*\s*(\d+) includes the numbers "2017" whrn I use it on "3C New 2017 program v1.2.3253.2.5beta52"

Comment: It doesn`t, with following example string (3C New 2017 program v1.2.3253.2.5beta52) it still includes the 2017 but it should remove it. I am using following regex (\d(\.\d*)*)+\s*\s*(\d+) Any suggestions? I am close.

Comment: put that input string here.

Comment: 3C New 2017 program v1.2.3253.2.5beta52 --> should result in 1.2.3253.2.552

Comment: OK I see the problem. Let me correct. I did not see the beta at the end

Comment: No problem JBone, the string could also be  
3C New 2017 program v1.2.3253.2.5 b52 , that makes it so hard.

Comment: Check now. Have more input strings in your original question if you can

Comment: I did, it captures 1.2.3253.2.5, pls check my updated questions for more input strings

Comment: so you are good now? the comma is not there in your string so it should not come unless you are printing it out in your own code

Comment: Still searching unfortuntaly if i check it with https://regexr.com/ it still only outputs "1.2.3253.2.5 "

Comment: I am stepping out. I will look into it a little later

Comment: No problem JBone, thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this

```
/(\d+\.)+\d+[a-z]*\d*/g
```

Matching any x. 1 or more times followed by a digit
This way all your versions will be extracted out if they follow the x.x format

This will return the version with the 'beta'
You can then use another regex on that string to exclude the illegal beta

```
/[^a-z]/g
```

Comment: Thx but this also leaves out the "last part" --> beta52 or b458 (52 or 458 should be included), pls check my updated question with some example inputs.

Comment: will it always be either b or beta followed by the number?

Comment: No but these are only examples, I should only get the correct version part, leaving out the illegal numeric values in front.

Comment: I have updated the answer, First i wanted to extract out the part of the string containing only the versioning info. After that we can work on removing the illegal letters.

Comment: Thx this works for the 1st example, it outputs 1.2.3253.2.5beta52 (I can then remove the non numeric characters) but it does not woth for the 2nd example, b458 is skipped.

Ok I see your edit now.

Comment: So can we presume that those two expressions suits all your edge cases?

Comment: I am testing Nanotron.

Comment: Does not wotk for the 2nd example in my question, I`ll have a look later on. Thx for your time Nanotron.

Comment: I think I found my combo: (\d+\.)+\s*\s*(\d+)|(\d+)(?!.*\d), I tested on multiple examples and they all pass.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of testing and searching, I found the pattern I need.
Upvotes for the answer of JBone and Nanotron, for pointing me in the right direction.

For anyone who wants to use it, here is the working code:

```
private String getVersion(String Str) {

        StringBuilder version = new StringBuilder();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.)+\\s*\\s*(\\d+)|(\\d+)(?!.*\\d)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(Str);

        while (m.find()) {

            version.append(m.group());
        }

        return version.toString();

    }
```

Results:

```
Str = "3C New 2017 program v1.2.3253.2.5beta52" --> 1.2.3253.2.552
Str = "3C New 2017 program v1.2.3253.2.5 b458" --> 1.2.3253.2.5458
```